# Pulse audio doesn't start on boot unless i run some commands

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, manjaro, i3

as the title says, pulse audio doesn't start when booting. I need to run

```
rm -rf /tmp/pulse* ~/.pulse* ~/.config/pulse
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

in order for it to start. I have even put these commands on an .sh and made this script to run on boot but it doesn's work unless i execute this file manually, sometimes i even have to run it twice.

- OS: Manjaro Linux with i3
- Pulseaudio: pulseaudio 13.0-dirty
- Audio Devices: `00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)` `00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)`

[+] Discord and Godot Engine can find any input or output devices!

Comment: If u downvote the post at least tell the reason why u downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up pulseaudio daemon in startup?

If not you can set up using following (depending on your linux version)

`systemctl enable pulseaudio` and `systemctl start pulseaudio`

Comment: i get this error ``Failed to enable unit: Unit file pulseaudio.service does not exist.
``

Comment: can u check  if pulseaudio is installed ?

Comment: yes it is ``> which pulseaudio``
``/usr/bin/pulseaudio``

Comment: and ``> pulseaudio --version``
``pulseaudio 13.0-dirty``

Comment: see if u can setup service manually, Here's a link on howto: https://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with pulseaudio on my Manjaro with i3. The problem was with `.i3/config`, I just commented line:

```
exec --no-startup-id pulseaudio
```

Also, you can try to restart pulseaudio after boot by adding this line to `.i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id systemctl --user restart pulseadio
```